# Jenkins and Xcode 8: unit test results not properly displayed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, jenkins

I am trying to set a jenkins job to execute the tests and display the results. I got the test to work, and the results to show but jenkins will not show me the results for every test, only a part of them, and repeating the same job with the same settings will get me a different test count each time...

[image: test count changing for the same job with the same settings on the same code base]

Looking in the test-reports folder shows me test reports appearing after the job has ended.
Test coverrage is showing without any problem though.

Is there a way to correct this and get jenkins to show all test results each time?

I am using the Xcode plugin for jenkins and the test relating settings are:

```
Custom xcodebuild arguments: test -destination 'platform=iOS  Simulator,OS=10.0,name=iPhone 7'
```

Clean test reports is set to true.

to display the tests I use the JUnit tool with test-reports/*.xml as path for the xml files.

Comment: we have this issue too. xcode 8.1, osx 10.12.1, sim 10.1.